# For loop in matlab plot

Tags: matlab, plot

Hello i am having some problems understading basic plotting in matlab. 
I can understand why you would use a for loop when plotting data?
Can anybody explain this to me?

I am making a simple linear plot. Is there any reason this should be inside a loop

Comment: Hi, and welcome to SO. Your question is a bit unclear... can you provide a specific example which you're having trouble understanding it?

Answer (score 0):

If you are making a simple plot there is virtually no reason to use a loop.

If you check `doc plot` you will find that plot can take some vectors as input, or even matrices for more interesting situations.

Example:

```
x=0:0.01:1;
y=sin(x);

plot(x,y)
```

Answer (score 0):

No there is no need in Matlab to use a for loop for plotting. If you are looking for a simple linear plot your code could look like this:

```
x=1:100;
y=3*x+4;
plot(x,y)
```

As you see there is no for loop needed. Same goes for nearly all plots and visualization.

Answer (score -1):

A possible reason to use a for loop to plot thing may be having several data to plot in a single matrix. Say you have two matrix `Ax (MxN)` and `Ay (MxN)` where **N** the length of each data and **M** is the amount of different data wanted to plot.  For example like in this case N is 201 and M is 3:

```
% Create Ax and Ay
Ax=meshgrid(0:0.1:20,1:3);
Ay=zeros(size(Ax));
% Sinusoidals with different frequencies
for k=1:3
   Ay(k,:)=sin(k.*Ax(k,:)); 
end
% create colours
colorVec = hsv(3);
% Plot
hold on
for k=1:3
  plot(Ax(k,:),Ay(k,:),'Color',colorVec(k,:))
end
hold off
```

You get:

[image]

Comment: Actuallly having a matrix is a case where you would NOT want to use a for loop for the plot. You could simply use something like `plot(Ax',Ay')`. This example again shows that for simple plots you won't need a loop in MATLAB. --- If you had a cell array with vectors of different length a loop may be desirable.

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin you are rigth, but the OP wanted an example of use. There are actually cases where you need for loops for plotting (you can find them widely in Matlab function help examples), I just wanted to put a simple case where it could be used, as the OP seems confused about basic plotting functioning.